# Google Maps v3 - How can I get all the markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

with this code I can show on the map just the first 20 markers obtained with the research.

```
        function initialize() {
            google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

            var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.900233,12.482132),
              zoom: 12,
              minZoom: 12,
              maxZoom: 16,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);


            var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                 new google.maps.LatLng(41.77336,12.338805), 
                 new google.maps.LatLng(42.046233,12.675261)
            );

            var request = {
              bounds: allowedBounds,
              query: "ristorante"
              };

            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.textSearch(request, callback);

            function callback(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                  var place = results[i];
                  createMarker(results[i]);
                }
              }
            }
            function createMarker(place) {
              var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
              });
            }
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But I would show on the map ALL the markers, at the same time and not just the first twenty. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for the third parameter in your callback:

```
function callback(results, status, pagination)...
```

That object can say if there is more results:

```
if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
  button.onClick = pagination.nextPage;
}
```

You have to decide the logic that make the call to the next page.

Comment: ok, but in this way I have always 20 results at time showed on the map, right? while i would see all the results at the same time on the map